# Transaction not active

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I got this problem and I can't see whats wrong.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
```

I want to get a Client by his id. So my code is:

```
... somewhere at UI Layer ... {
     ... 
     Cliente c = ServicesFactory.getClientService().clientWith(id);
     ... 
}
```

Where clientWith is something like:

```
@Override
    public Cliente clientWith(Long id) throws BusinessException {
        return (Cliente) executor.execute(new FindClientByID(id));
    }
```

And FindClientById is a command with this code

```
public class FindClientByID implements Command {

    private Long id;

    public FindClientByID(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute() throws BusinessException {
        return ClienteFinder.findById(id);
    }
}
```

And ClienteFinder is:

```
public class ClienteFinder {

    public static Cliente findById(Long id) {
        return Jpa.getManager().find(Cliente.class, id);
    }
}
```

The class Cliente I think it's well mapped. Where my code fails and why?

**EDIT**

Ok, my code is crashing at method execute() of FindClientByID but I really don't know why. The call seems to throw a RuntimeException.

Btw, my Command Executor is something like

```
public Object execute(Command command) throws BusinessException {

        EntityManager em = Jpa.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trx = em.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();

        Object ret = null;
        try {
            ret = command.execute(); // <-- This line throws RuntimeException
            trx.commit();
        } catch (BusinessException bex) {
            if(trx.isActive())
                trx.rollback();
            throw bex;
        } catch (RuntimeException tex) {
            if(trx.isActive())
                trx.rollback();
            trx.rollback();
            throw  tex;
        } finally {
            if(em.isOpen())
                em.close();
        }



        return ret;
    }
```

Thanks guys : D

Comment: What kind of transaction do you use?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just newbie on this. How I can check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at one catch. Thanks guys.

```
public Object execute(Command command) throws BusinessException {

        EntityManager em = Jpa.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trx = em.getTransaction();
        trx.begin();

        Object ret = null;
        try {
            ret = command.execute(); // <-- This line throws RuntimeException
            trx.commit();
        } catch (BusinessException bex) {
            if(trx.isActive())
                trx.rollback();
            throw bex;
        } catch (RuntimeException tex) {
            if(trx.isActive())
                trx.rollback();
            trx.rollback(); <--- **The problem was here.**
            throw  tex;
        } finally {
            if(em.isOpen())
                em.close();
        }



        return ret;
    }
```